# Combining arrays with common values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of dates that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => '2014-01-01'
    [1] => '2014-01-02'
    [2] => '2014-01-03'
    [3] => '2014-01-04'
    [4] => '2014-01-05'
    [5] => '2014-01-06'
    [6] => '2014-01-07'
)
```

and I have another array of dates and counts that looks like this:

```
[All] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count] => 2
                [date] => 2014-01-06
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [date] => 2014-01-03
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [count] => 43
                [date] => 2013-12-11
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [count] => 103
                [date] => 2013-12-10
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [count] => 128
                [date] => 2013-12-09
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [count] => 75
                [date] => 2013-12-08
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [count] => 107
                [date] => 2013-12-07
            )
```

I want to make a new associative array where all the keys are the dates from the first array above and all of the values are either the count matched up with the corresponding date or "0".

So for instance, the new array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [2014-01-01] => 0
    [2014-01-02] => 0
    [2014-01-03] => 1
    [2014-01-04] => 0
    [2014-01-05] => 0
    [2014-01-06] => 2
    [2014-01-07] => 0
)
```

Does that make sense? Please feel free to ask any questions you may have. Thank you!

Comment: First question: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried a foreach inside of a for loop, but I was getting back too many results.

Comment: Second question: can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: foreach `ALL` array and check if `date` key exists in your first array.

Comment: use php.net and read up on array_merge, array_unique and array_filter. Can save you ALOT of ugly foreach loops

Comment: @u_mulder I tried that but then I was unsure what to do with the values once I found a match between the two arrays.

Comment: Put them into new array - `date => ALL[]['count']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$result = array();
foreach($firstArray as $f){
    foreach($secondArray as $s){
        if($s['date'] == $f) $result[$f] = $s['count'];
    }
    if(!array_key_exists($f, $result)) $result[$f] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach($secondArray as $s){
    if(in_array($s['date'], $firstArray) {
        unset($firstArray[$s['date']]);
        $result[$s['date']] = $s['count'];
    }        
}

// if items left in first array that are not found within foreach:
if (!empty($firstArray))
    $result = array_merge($result, array_fill_keys($firstArray, 0));

// sort by key so dates go ascending
ksort($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = array();

foreach($all as $row)
{
       $new[$row['date']] = $row['count'];
}

array_merge ($new, $old);
```

Here `$all` is the array with the date and count indices. 
`$old` is the exisisting array.

Comment: Merged array will have a mix of keys - strings and integers.

Answer (score 0):

That's a 2-liner:

```
// use dates as index and set everything to 0
$result = array_fill_keys($x, 0));
// copy over existing counts
array_walk($all, function($v) use (&$result) { if (array_key_exists($v['date'], $result)) { $result[$v['date']] = $v['count'];}});
```